# Update multiple rows with CASE takes forever

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update multiple rows of a table with the following PHP code. main_key is the primary key and is obviously indexed. I have tried to run the code multiple times and every time I do it just sits there for ages. (I have not been game to leave it running for more than about 10 seconds in case it is trashing the file somehow.)

I want to update lots of rows but am just testing with a couple of lines first.

The table has around 1.5M records.

```
$query = "UPDATE myfile SET service_no = 
(CASE main_key
     WHEN 72016 THEN 484
     WHEN 985643 THEN 1874
END)";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

When I change the code to a normal single-record update like this it runs instantly:

```
$query = "UPDATE myfile SET service_no = 484
          WHERE main_key = 72016";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what are you trying to get.
These two queries are quite different.
Do you want to update all rows ? Or only rows where `main_key` is 72016 or 985643 ?

The first query updates the whole table (all rows).
Say we have the following table:

```
|  MAIN_KEY | SERVICE_NO |
|-----------|------------|
|         1 |          1 |
|     72016 |          1 |
|    985643 |          1 |
| 111111111 |          1 |
```

The first query assing some values to the `service_no` column for rows which have `main_key = 72016 or 985643`, and assign NULL to all other rows. I'ts slow, because it is changing the whole table (all rows):

```
|  MAIN_KEY | SERVICE_NO |
|-----------|------------|
|         1 |     (null) |
|     72016 |        484 |
|    985643 |       1874 |
| 111111111 |     (null) |
```

The second query changes only rows which have `mail_key = 72016`, and doesn't touch the other rows - it skips them, and therefore it's faster:

```
|  MAIN_KEY | SERVICE_NO |
|-----------|------------|
|         1 |          1 |
|     72016 |        484 |
|    985643 |          1 |
| 111111111 |          1 |
```

Take a look at this demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e1c2/1

If you want to change only rows which have `main_key = 72016 or 985643`, and don't want to change the other rows, then use this query:

```
  UPDATE myfile SET service_no = 
     CASE main_key
        WHEN 72016 THEN 484
        WHEN 985643 THEN 1874
     END
  WHERE main_key IN ( 72016, 985643 );
```

If there is an index created on `main_key`, this query will be faster, since it skips other rows than 72016, 985643.
See a third query in this demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e1c2/1

The table after running this query looks like this:

```
|  MAIN_KEY | SERVICE_NO |
|-----------|------------|
|         1 |          1 |
|     72016 |        484 |
|    985643 |       1874 |
| 111111111 |          1 |
```